# What means "not running under some shell" in Perl scripts?

Tags: perl, cpan

In many perl scripts (especially in famous CPAN distros) I find the following piece of code:

```
eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -w -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
if 0; # not running under some shell
```

I was wondering what it is for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some systems don't recognize the `#!/usr/bin/perl` line at the start of scripts, and so trying to invoke a Perl program by name on such a system will simply pass the script to the shell.  In order to combat this, portable Perl programs begin with a line that, when interpreted by a standard POSIX shell, causes the script to be passed to `perl(1)` instead.  The `if 0` causes the line to be ignored when run by Perl itself, and placing it on a separate line causes shells to treat it as a separate command, running just the `eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -w -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'` as soon as it's read.

Comment: Thanks, very much! How clever really!

Comment: I wonder if there are still any systems worth worrying about that don't support [shebangs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Comment: I have scripts that do this so that they will run under Solaris AND Linux. The shebang points to a Solaris perl, but under Linux the script executes as shell, and the eval line executes a Linux perl. The perls are installed under odd locations, but files/directories are shared between systems via NFS.

Answer (score 2):

The line is valid under shells as well as perl. In perl `eval` is skipped because of following `if 0`. In shell, same file is executed in `perl` using the eval.