# Perl "use: command not found" when run from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, perl, syntax-error, command-line-interface

I have a Perl script `Info.perl` which starts like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!/usr/bin/bash

use List::Util qw( min max );
use List::MoreUtils qw{ all any };
use Cwd;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use Env qw(INFODIR CONFDIR PROCDIR);
```

And when I run it from the terminal it gives no problem and works as expected.

But then I have a bash script `run.sh` that only has in it

```
./Info.pl
```

And when I run this script I get the following error

```
./Info.pl: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./Info.pl: line 4: `use List::Util qw( min max );'
```

If I omit line 4 I get the following message:

```
./Info.pl: line 5: use: command not found
./Info.pl: line 6: use: command not found
./Info.pl: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./Info.pl: line 7: `use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);'
```

Is there any special way I need to run the Perl script inside the bash script? Or any special way to use the `use` command?

Comment: Do you actually have the 2 shebang lines in your perl script?

Comment: Sounds like your file is being executed as bash script, not as Perl script.

Comment: How are you running it from the terminal? Is the `Info.pl` file set executable?

Comment: Two shebang lines isn't a problem. Only the first matters. The second will be seen as a comment by perl and ignored. It isn't useful and shouldn't be there though.

Comment: Do you have perl installed in directory /usr/bin?

Comment: Tanks for the clarifications. I removed the redundants line. @EtanReisner I clarified in the post now how I run it from the terminal, both scripts.

Comment: Are you sure your bash-script looks like that? It doesn't have ". ./Info.pl"?

Comment: Please post the script you actually ran. The error message says `use List::Util` is on line 4, but it's on line 3 in the code you posted.

Comment: Please don't screw up the question by fixing the problem. Now it doesn't make sense anymore (the problem seems to have been the line you removed).

Comment: Removing that extra shebang line does not alter the error or the problem in any way. It simply removes a line that confused some people. Yes, it threw the line numbers off. That's unfortunate but not material to the problem.

Comment: Assuming that is the correct location for perl on your system then the problem is almost certainly that `Info.pl` is simply not marked executable and so the shebang line is being ignored and the current shell is trying to execute the script instead.

Comment: @EtanReisner That would result in a `Permission denied` error, no? asjo's explanation (sourcing the Perl script instead of executing it) seems more likely.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Probably but not necessarily. Yes, it does but it was indicated that wasn't being done. The perl path being wrong is also possible.

Comment: @EtanReisner 1) In what circumstances will the shell ignore the shebang and try to interpret a script that doesn't have the execute bit set when run with the `./foo` syntax? I'm curious, I've never heard of this before. 2) In your second sentence, are you saying there's evidence that the Perl script wasn't being sourced, or are you just referring to what the OP said?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I think I may have mis-remembered the situation there. I think I was thinking of other failure modes for which the shell may fall back to self-executing the script but not executable permissions being missing. And yes, I'm going by what the OP said they did when running the script. We don't have any information beyond that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been told in the comments, your script for some reason is getting executed via shell. You can study why it is so and fix it.

Or you can work around using the following trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl "$0" "$@"'
    if 0; # not running under some shell

print "Args: @ARGV\n";
```

If this script is evaluated via perl, `if 0;` line prevents the eval from execution.

However, shell doesn't have postfix conditions, so it just executes the first line, which runs the correct interpreter.

In fact, a number, no, a **NUMBER** of perl scripts start that way. Google this "not running under some shell" for examples (and an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143726/what-means-not-running-under-some-shell-in-perl-scripts) on SO).

Comment: The standard Perl distribution installers will add that to scripts when it installs them

Comment: @ikegami Ah, so that's where it comes from. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. I'll mark this answer as correct since its more explanatory than the other one (though the other one was first).

Comment: If this solved the problem I'd still like to know what was going on. Was the path correct? Was the shebang line correct? Was the script executable? Was it being sourced (`. Info.pl` or `. ./Info.pl`) instead of being executed (`./Info.pl')? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Removing '#!/usr/bin/bash' would be a good idea as it is redundant.
Calling '/usr/bin/perl Info.pl' in your script may fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you, this worked (I got confused at first as I included the ' ' in the command.